# Accessing elements from a dictionary? Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to access elements from a dictionary by giving them variables so that I can use them in other functions, but it keeps tell me that it is not defined.

The file I am using (mood.txt):

```
happy, Jennifer Clause
happy, Jake Foster
sad, Jonathan Bower
mad, Penny
excited, Logan 
awkward, Mason Tyme
```

my code:

```
def theFile():
    moodFile = open("mood.txt")
    theMood = moodFile.readlines()
    moodFile.close()
    return(theMood)

def makeTheDict(myFile):
    moodDict = {}

    for lines in myFile:
        (mood, name) = lines.split(",")

        moodDict[mood] = name.strip()

    return(moodDict)


def printMood(mood, moodDict):

    if mood in moodDict:
        print("The people who are", mood, ":", name)


def main():

    moodFile = theFile()

    moodDict = makeTheDict(moodFile)

    findMood = input("Which mood do you want to choose?: ")
    printMood(findMood, moodDict)
```

I keep getting this error:

```
NameError: global name 'name' is not defined
```

I hope someone can explain to me what I'm doing wrong! Thanks!

Comment: you haven't posted your actual code, because if you did you would get an error here about lines being undefined `(mood, name) = lines.split(",")`

Comment: sorry something must've went wrong while i was trying to type and look at it at the same time..

Comment: ok I see what i did!! i fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't define the `name` in your function. use `moodDict[mood]` to ge the name:

```
def printMood(mood, moodDict):
    if mood in moodDict:
        print("The people who are", mood, ":", moodDict[mood])
```

Or just use `dict.get()` attribute which accepts a default argument to return in case of not existing the key. Which makes you get ride of `if` condition and the comparison in each iteration:

```
def printMood(mood, moodDict):
    print("The people who are", mood, ":", moodDict.get(mood, '-')) #  you can use any default string instead of '-'.
```

Comment: Thank you! This makes so much more sense now!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this line is the problem:

```
if mood in moodDict:
    print("The people who are", mood, ":", name)
```

Try:

```
if mood, names in moodDict.iteritems():
    print("The people who are", mood, ":", names)
```